# Open URL stored in a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I'm almost an absolute beginner in Python, but I am  asked to manage some difficult task. I have read many tutorials and found some very useful tips on this website, but I think that this question was not asked until now, or at least in the way I tried it in the search engine.

I have managed to write some url in a csv file. Now I would like to write a script able to open this file, to open the urls, and write their content in a dictionary. But I have failed : my script can print these addresses, but cannot process the file.

Interestingly, my script dit not send the same error message each time. Here the last : req.timeout = timeout
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'timeout'

So I think my script faces several problems :
 1- is my method to open url the right one ?
2 -  and what is wrong in the way I build the dictionnary ?

Here is my attempt below. Thanks in advance to those who would help me !

```
import csv
import urllib

dict = {}

test = csv.reader(open("read.csv","rb"))

for z in test:  
    sock = urllib.urlopen(z)
    source = sock.read()
    dict[z] = source
    sock.close()
print dict
```

Comment: You shouldn't name your dictionary `dict`, you overrite the builtin `dict` with that assignment. Instead of using `urllib` you should use `urllib2`, not sure if this solves your problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, don't shadow built-ins. Rename your dictionary to something else as `dict` is used to create new dictionaries.

Secondly, the `csv` reader creates a list per line that would contain all the columns. Either reference the column explicitly by `urllib.urlopen(z[0])  # First column in the line` or open the file with a normal `open()` and iterate through it.

Apart from that, it works for me.

Comment: Thanks guys for these quick and useful answers ! It seems that it remains an error : now i get this :     dico[z] = source
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'  Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Dicts only accept immutable types: numbers, strings, tuples. Lists are mutable. You would want to use the url, which will be z[0].

Comment: That's because `z` is a list. Just as you changed the value you're passing to `urlopen` to `z[0]` so should you change where you add it to your dictionary to `z[0]`.